# jQuery Call Button Click from other Button

Tags: jquery

I want to `call` a `button click` from `another button`. So if I click the first button - the second button should trigger. I have the following code.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="submit" name="savebutton" id="first" />
<a href="http://www.google.com/">
 <input type="submit" name="savebutton" id="second" />
</a>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function(){
  $('#first').click(function() {
   $("#second").trigger('click'); // $('#second').click(); wont work either
  });
});
```

Link to my Fiddle: [**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/y47AL/1/)

I cant figure out what iam doing wrong - can some one please explain it to me?

Comment: I don't see any click event assigned to the second button. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/y47AL/2/

Comment: It's working fine http://jsfiddle.net/y47AL/4/

Comment: Or did you mean to `click` the hyperlink? In that case, try: `location.href = $("#second").parent().attr('href');`

Comment: @tewathia oh i thought i can trigger the link with the click - thank you explaining this to me.

Comment: @Mr.iC You *can* trigger the link. http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/y47AL/8/. You won't see google open in the fiddle(jsfiddle has some cross-domain issues, it would work if you create your own html page), but in the console you can see that the link was triggered. **Edit:** `window.open` would also work. See http://jsfiddle.net/tewathia/y47AL/9/

Comment: @tewathia oh didnt knew that - thx for pointing that out - it will  sure improve my jQuery Learning curve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works but you don't have handler on the second! The click event got fired but you don't say what should happen...

Here is a code example and a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Vandeplas/65kg9/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#first').click(function() {
        alert('button clicked');
        $("#second").trigger('click');
    });

    $("#second").click(function() {
       alert('button 2 clicked!');
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you - my bad - thought i can trigger the link with the click.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/y47AL/6/)

```
$(function(){
    $('#first').click(function(e) {
        alert('first')
        $("#second").submit();

        e.preventDefault()

    });
    $('#second').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault()
       alert('second')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work , this is valid code

```
$(function(){
  $('#first').click(function() {
   $("#second").trigger('click'); // 
  });
});
```

Incase your buttons are dynamic then you can try

```
$('#first').on('click' ,function(){
  $("#second").trigger('click');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $('#first').click(function() {
      $("#second").trigger('click');
});


 $('#second').click(function() {
     alert($(this).parent().attr('href'))   
     window.open($(this).parent().attr('href'));
    //for opening in same window use window.location=$(this).parent().attr('href')
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/y47AL/7/)**